# Detect empty cells in rows with multiple columns and remove them in r

Tags: r

I want to find all the empty rows in specific columns and then remove them. I was able to do so:

```
#specify which one is empty in gender, education level,and industry
which(msUS$Gender =="",arr.ind = TRUE)
which(msUS$Education_Level=="",arr.ind = TRUE)
which(msUS$Industry=="",arr.ind = TRUE)
#remove the empty rows
msUS <-msUS[!(msUS$Gender==""),]
msUS <-msUS[!(msUS$Education_Level==""),]
msUS <-msUS[!(msUS$Industry==""),]
#check num of rows & columns
```

Is there any smarter way to do it?

Comment: why not use `i1 <- which(myUS[c("Gender", "Education_Level", "Industry")] == "", arr.ind = TRUE)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we want to do this on another way, instead of `which` with `arr.ind` performed on single column, create a logical matrix with the selected columns, and then check the count of blank (`""`) in each row with `rowSums`, and then select only rows having no blanks (`==0`)

```
myUS[rowSums(myUS[c("Gender", "Education_Level", "Industry")] == "") == 0,]
```

---

Another option is `if_any` with `filter` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
myUS %>%
    filter(!if_any(c(Gender, Education_Level, Industry), ~ .x == ""))
```

Or with `if_all` with `!=`

```
myUS %>%
    filter(if_all(c(Gender, Education_Level, Industry), ~ .x != ""))
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks for giving me so much methods to explore! These are really helpful!